# console getElementById returns null

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Okay so i'm trying to add a script to my HTML file, but couldn't do so. I found out that when I try to console log the ids, they all returns null.

```
console.log(document.getElementById('forms'))
console.log(document.getElementById('signIn'))
console.log(document.getElementById('signUp'))
```

So here's the full code of my HTML file:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('forms'))
console.log(document.getElementById('signIn'))
console.log(document.getElementById('signUp'))
```

```html
<div class="container" id="forms">
  <div class="overlay-container">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-left">
        <h2>Welcome Back!</h2>
        <p>Please login with your personal info</p>
        <button class="invert" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-right">
        <h2>Hello, Friend!</h2>
        <p>Please enter your personal details</p>
        <button class="invert" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class="sign-up" action="#">
    <h2>Create login</h2>
    <div>Use your email for registration</div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button>Sign Up</button>
  </form>
  <form class="sign-in" action="#">
    <h2>Sign In</h2>
    <div>Use your account</div>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
    <button>Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Not if you do it after the forms have rendered. See your snippet. It works. EITHER put the script at the bottom of the page OR wrap in a load eventListener

Comment: Voting to close as `Not reproducible or was caused by a typo
While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a way less likely to help future readers.`

Answer (score 0):

You want to make sure your DOM is loaded so that you can access the elements with `getElementById` otherwise you're going to get `null` as an output.

I've modified your snippet to add an event listener to the `Window load` event that will only print to the console the output of getElementById after the whole page has been loaded.

Read more about the Window load event here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
  console.log(document.getElementById('forms'))
  console.log(document.getElementById('signIn'))
  console.log(document.getElementById('signUp'))
});
```

```html
<div class="container" id="forms">
  <div class="overlay-container">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="overlay-left">
        <h2>Welcome Back!</h2>
        <p>Please login with your personal info</p>
        <button class="invert" id="signIn">Sign In</button>
      </div>
      <div class="overlay-right">
        <h2>Hello, Friend!</h2>
        <p>Please enter your personal details</p>
        <button class="invert" id="signUp">Sign Up</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <form class="sign-up" action="#">
    <h2>Create login</h2>
    <div>Use your email for registration</div>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button>Sign Up</button>
  </form>
  <form class="sign-in" action="#">
    <h2>Sign In</h2>
    <div>Use your account</div>
    <input type="email" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <a href="#">Forgot your password?</a>
    <button>Sign Up</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably including the `<script>` tag inside the `<head>` tag, so the script is being executed before the elements are mounted into the DOM, and `getElementById()` calls are returning `null`.

If that's the case, you might want to move the `<script>` tag inside the `<body>` tag as its last child. While this doesn't guarantee that the entire page is *loaded* before your script runs, it does guarantee that all elements before it are inserted into the `DOM`.

So instead of this:

```html
<html>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
<body>
    ...
</body>
</html>
```

You can do this:

```html
<html>
    ...
<body>
    ...
    <script type="text/javascript">...</script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also wait for the `load` event of the `window` before running your scripts (e.g. `window.addEventListener('load', ...)`, which makes the placement of the `<script>` tag irrelevant, but it may defer your execution much longer than needed as it waits for *all* elements to be loaded, including images or videos.

Answer (score 0):

For me the component I was trying to get wasn't rendered yet. After I added a setTimeout then check document.getElementById() it worked